# How write test for logics in retry function on Alamofire.Interceptor

Tags: swift, unit-testing, testing, interceptor

I use the Alamofire.Interceptor to handle refresh token and retry some API calls and I have a lot of logic and if / else's on this network interceptor class.

I wonder how I can write unit test for this class and especially the "retry" delegate function in this class

```
// Called when status code is not 200...299 or in failure
func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {
    guard let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 401 else {
        // request failed not because 401 but something 
        // else I will have my custom logics here :)
        return completion(.doNotRetryWithError(error))
    }
    guard request.retryCount < retryLimit else {
        completion(.doNotRetry)
        return
    }
    
    // if we retry then request is not proceed error handling in above
    // if doNotRetry then do nothing
    AuthService.shared.fetchAuthSession() { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success:
            completion(.retry)
        case .failure:
            self?.forceUserRelog()
            completion(.doNotRetry)
        }
    }
}
```

I could extract the logic in a separate class or a static function, but I don't know if it is the best way.